# Incorrect syntax error in unix script while using if exists command (sybase as database)

Tags: shell-script, sql

I have the below script presenting me the following error:

```
isql -U$DBLogin -PDBPAss -S$DBName -e <<!
   use $db
go
   if exists (select 1 from syscolumns where id = object_id('Main_table')  and name = 'Stamm')
   begin
   insert into Main_table select * from temp_table
   end
   else
   begin
   create table Main_table
   (
    Stamm char (5),
    Datum int,
    Perdat char (5) null
   )
go
   insert into Main_table select * from temp_table
   end
go
DROP TABLE temp_table
go
!
```

When I execute this I have been getting the below error even being tried for so many times.

Error Details: (log)

```
1>    use db
1>    if exists (select 1 from syscolumns where id = object_id('Main_table') and name = 'Stamm')
2>    begin
3>    insert into Main_table select * from temp_table
4>    end
5>    else
6>    begin
7>    create table Main_table
8>    (
9>         Stamm char (5),
10>         Datum int,
11>         Perscd char (5) null
12>    )
Msg 102, Level 15, State 181:
Server 'DB_DEVP', Line 12:
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
1>    insert into Main_table select * from temp_table
2>    end
Msg 156, Level 15, State 2:
Server 'DB_DEVP', Line 2:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'end'.
1>    DROP TABLE db..temp_table
```

Comment: On line 13, you have a `go` statement, which means the `begin` statement on line 6 may be perceived as having no matching `end` statement.   Does it run if you remove the `go` after the `create table`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a shell scripting issue but an issue with the syntax of your SQL.

From the error output:

```
1>    use db
1>    if exists (select 1 from syscolumns where id = object_id('Main_table') and name = 'Stamm')
2>    begin
```

It looks like the first two lines are taken as a single command and this may be why the database engine detects a syntax error. It may need to be delimited into two commands. I don't know Sybase, but try using `use $db;` as the first line of the here-document.

Apart from that, there is nothing terribly wrong with your shell script. The only thing I would comment on is the lack of double-quoting of the `$DBLogin` and `$DBName` parameter expansions, and the very unconventional (albeit legal) delimiter for the here-document that you redirect into the `isql` command (I would have used `END_SQL` or similar).

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I don't see any issue with use $db - there we have been trying to tell to connect to required schema.
I could see the if exists statement is killing me.
I have tried your way and didn't succeed.